# Make module load JSON Karma AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, json, karma-jasmine, karma-runner

I have a project built in AngularJS and I want to add unit test using Jasmine and Karma. Everytime I try to run a test I get 'Failed to instantiate module' because in the source code I load a local json file using XMLHttpRequest but in the test the same function respond with a 404. The json is a configuration file so if it's not loaded all the app can not be loaded properly. I tried with $httpBackend to capture the GET request and answer with a custom json but seems that $httpBackend cannot capture the request.

EDIT

I think the problem is the same of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31473075/how-to-serve-json-files-in-karma)

Answer (score 0):

You can use mock data from JSON file by picking it up using `require()` function:

```
const data: any = require('../../assets/sample-data.json');
```

Now you should be able to use `data` object in your tests.
Or You can convert your json data to an Angular service (actually an Angular constant can work). Then my external file will be easy to grab in the tests, ex:

```
var setupData = $injector.get('SampleData');
$httpBackend.whenGET('/my-service-url').respond(SampleData);
$httpBackend.flush();
```

Comment: Tank you for the response. I tried some stuff including yours but the problems seems to be when the module is injected, that happen before the execution of your code. It seems like jasmine or karma cannot include the file when creating the test environment. I tried to add the path in the karma.conf.js with no success